# How to use SimpleGUIS2Pygame load picture?

Tags: python, codeskulptor

I follow the Coursera course "[An Introduction to Interactive Programming in Python](https://www.coursera.org/course/interactivepython1)".

I try to practice something on my own computer. I found the package "[SimpleGUICS2Pygame](https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/)" which can replace the `simplegui` of [CodeSkulptor](http://www.codeskulptor.org/).

Now, I want to load a picture with this function: [`load_image()`](https://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.io/en/latest/simpleguics2pygame/image.html#SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame.image.load_image). But the error says: at line 6: "AssertionError: Pygame not available!"

So I have to install pygame from the [Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/) website. But it still the same error. I have no idea, why pygame not available. (I use windows 8.1). Following is my code, it is an example from the codeskulptor:

```
import SimpleGUICS2Pygame.simpleguics2pygame as simplegui

def draw_handler(canvas):
    canvas.draw_image(image, (1521 / 2, 1818 / 2), (1521, 1818), (50, 50), (100, 100))

image = simplegui.load_image('http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/gutenberg.jpg')

frame = simplegui.create_frame('Testing', 100, 100)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw_handler)
frame.start()
```

Thanks very much for the help!

Comment: *Maybe* have you several versions of Python on your computer. And *maybe* have you installed Pygame on the "wrong" version or in the wrong place.
Run the `SimpleGUICS2Pygame_check.py` script and tell me the result:
https://bitbucket.org/OPiMedia/simpleguics2pygame/src/default/SimpleGUICS2Pygame/script/

The online documentation: http://simpleguics2pygame.readthedocs.org/

Comment: Hi @OPi , thanks very much for the answer! Yes, I installed the python(x,y) and installed also anaconda. I did the check with your code: 1) use default python: I got the error message: import pygame FAILED! No module named pygame.  2) with the anaconda: I got the error message: import pygame FAILED! DLL load failed: %1 ist keine zulässige Win32-Anwendung. (This is german, means: import pygame FAILED! DLL load failed: %1 is not an allowed Win32-appliation. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `import pygame FAILED! No module named pygame` means Pygame is **not** installed for this version of Python.
- `import pygame FAILED! DLL load failed` probably means you have installed a wrong version of Pygame for this version of Python.

Here is several versions of Pygame:
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Choose the correct one that corresponds to your OS and your version of Python, 32 or 64 bits.

### Update

I have added a little script to check the Pygame installation alone:
[script/](https://bitbucket.org/OPiMedia/simpleguics2pygame/src/default/SimpleGUICS2Pygame/script/)pygame_check.py

Comment: Hi OPi, thanks very much. I fixed this problem under your direction!

Comment: Hi OPi, I write here my concrete solution: 1) For the normal python, I have no idea, why pip install SimpleGUICS2Pygame didn't install the pygame. I also used the windows installer 32 Bit MSI Version to install it. But I can not find pygame in my system library. So I downloaded the windows binary version follow your link. Use `pip install D:\mypygame_directory\pygit2‑0.21.3‑cp27‑none‑win_amd32.whl` . It works!!! 2) For the anaconda python. I just use the anaconda's pip do the same thing. So the problem also be settled! :D